# How to Dynamically create views in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

### How to  Dynamically create Views in Hibernate

> As per the requirement I have to dynamically create views in Hibernate.
>   I want to know is it possible in hibernate or not. If yes, then please provide some details and workaround of it.. how it works internally...

Experts ... Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon the blatent copy and paste, but this seems to be what you're after:

> 19.1. Hibernate filters
>
> Hibernate3 has the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach those filters at both a class level and a
>   collection level. A filter criteria allows you to define a restriction
>   clause similar to the existing "where" attribute available on the
>   class and various collection elements. These filter conditions,
>   however, can be parameterized. The application can then decide at
>   runtime whether certain filters should be enabled and what their
>   parameter values should be. **Filters can be used like database views,
>   but they are parameterized inside the application**.

Checkout the hibernate reference documentation for code snippets and post back if you get stuck on implementation details... My quote was from doc version 3.6.3...

Comment: I like this answer.  It is a most polite rehashing of "RTFM".